# sysctl.conf ignore net settings

Tags: 10.04

I have a little problem with sysctl on a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system.

When I set the sysctl values with "sysctl -w " all work fine, but when I try to use the sysctl.conf file. the net settings will be ignored.

**For example my sysctl.conf**

```
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables

kernel.domainname=findme.sysctl 

# Corefiles information 
fs.suid_dumpable=2 
kernel.core_pattern=/cores/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t

##############################################################3
# Functions previously found in netbase

net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait=1
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait=1
```

when I grep to the values, I can see that the sysctl settings for net.ipv4.netfilter don't set.

```
[host:~ ] $ sysctl -a | grep domainname
kernel.domainname = findme.sysctl

[host:~ ] $ sysctl -a | grep "core_pattern"
kernel.core_pattern = /cores/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t

[host:~ ] $ sysctl -a | grep "timeout_fin_wait"
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_fin_wait = 120

[host:~ ] $ sysctl -a | grep "timeout_close_wait"
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait = 60
```

can somebody help me to solve the problem?

If you need more information I can post it.

Cheers,

Steffen

Comment: Setting such a short value for nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_{close,fin}_wait will make almost every conntrack/ state rule useless. The defaults are 60 and 120 respectively. Such a low value make it impossible to track established connections as these will be marked as "new" very soon.

Answer (score 0):

> When I set the sysctl values with "sysctl -w " all work fine, but when I try to use the sysctl.conf file. the net settings will be ignored.

You should run `sysctl -p` for the effects to take change after editing sysctl.conf

From sysctl man page:

-p: Load in sysctl settings from the file specified or /etc/sysctl.conf if none given.

Comment: yes I know, this was a example that I can set this values... But thank you... I found a little syntax problem in my file and look if it work now ...

Comment: @SteffenUnland Did this helped actually?